# How do I send multiple form inputs in a post request react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build an app like pinterest that takes an image, a title, and a description (as well as user info but im not there yet) and sends a post request from the NewImage.jsx page, allowing it to display on the Home.jsx page.

**NewImage.jsx**

```
    return (
        <div className="newimage-page">
            <form>
            <div className="placement">
                <div className="alignRow">
                    <div className="addphoto">
                        <AddNew></AddNew>
                    </div>
                    <div className="info">
                        <SaveButton />
                        <div className="expandingArea">
                            <textarea wrap="soft" 
                                      placeholder="Add Your Title" 
                                      className="title" 
                                      rows="1"
                                      maxchars="100"
                                     ></textarea>
                            <textarea placeholder="Description" 
                                      className="description"  
                                      rows="1"
                                      maxchars="500"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
         </div>
```

I am trying to get the value of both text areas, as well as the photo infomation from the AddNew component

**AddNew.jsx**

```
const AddNew = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState('')
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }
    return (
        <div className="addNew">
            <div className="uploadstyle">
                <img src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : null} alt={file ? file.name : null} />
                <input className="upload" type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

how can i make it so when i click the save button component (which currently does nothing) i can post the values of all these items at once?

Comment: You could use controlled inputs https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components then add an onClick handler to your save button and issue your post request there. Or you could you use a simple form button, make your own onSubmit with prevent default, use some vanilla javascript to get the dom elements and read their values. I advise against this last option personally.

Answer (score 0):

- Maintain the form form data in your main form.
- Pass a handler for fileOnSelect to your `AddNew` component.
- Make use of `FormData`

Working copy of your code is here. You can take it forward and enhance or tweak it to your needs

**Main Form Component**

````js
export const Form = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const onSave = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('title', title);
        formData.append('description', description);
        console.log('formData', formData);
        fetch('/url', {method: 'POST',body: formData}).then(response => console.log(response));
    };

    return (
        <div className="newimage-page">
            <form>
                <div className="placement">
                    <div className="alignRow">
                        <div className="addphoto">
                            <AddNew onFileSelected={setFile}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="info">
                            {/*<SaveButton onSave={onSave}/>*/}
                            <button onClick={onSave}>Save</button>
                            <div className="expandingArea">
                            <textarea wrap="soft"
                                      // onChange={e => setForm(prevState => ({...prevState, title: e.target.value}))}
                                      onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                                      placeholder="Add Your Title"
                                      className="title"
                                      rows="1"
                                      maxchars="100"
                            />
                                <textarea placeholder="Description"
                                          onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                                          className="description"
                                          rows="1"
                                          value={description}
                                          maxchars="500"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>)
};

**AddNew Component** where you have the file input
```js
//separate file
const AddNew = ({onFileSelected}) => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState('');
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
        onFileSelected(event.target.files[0])//single file select
    };
    return (
        <div className="addNew">
            <div className="uploadstyle">
                <img src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : null} alt={file ? file.name : null} />
                <input className="upload" type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
````